# How can I downgrade Windows 7 Ultimate to Professional edition?

Tags: windows-7, downgrade, windows-edition

I’m trying to downgrade Windows 7 from the Ultimate edition to the Professional edition. I followed the [steps recommended](http://www.unawave.de/installation/downgrade-en.html) about modifying the registry, but they didn’t work.

How can I downgrade?

Comment: What steps recommended? What errors did you see? Your question as it stands is unanswerable.

Comment: I modified the register changing editionID and product name from Ultimate to professional as mentioned in UNAWAVE solution . then start setup of the professinal windows but gave me that I cannot install.

Answer (score 1):

In normally you can't downgrade a Microsoft OS to minor version but if you insist just follow this link, I just already test it in virtual machine and worked well.
[Downgrade MS OS](http://www.unawave.de/installation/downgrade-en.html?lang=EN)

Comment: i tried this solution , it didnt work

Comment: Are you sure you tried correctly all of steps and notes? because I tested and get answered in virtual machine.

Comment: Yes , I followed then thre times correctly . My windows ultimate is build 7601

Comment: I don't know why you can't get answered but i do install windows 7 ultimate with no any update no service pack and just follow the commands to downgrade to Home premium . may be you must first uninstall your updates ... i don't guarantied it's work after do this, it's up to you.

Comment: How can I uninstall updates ?

Comment: go to windows update , then on left side click on view update history . after that on the top there a link as said "install update" so just click on it and you can see all of your windows update that installed on you system . to uninstall it just double click on each one you want.